# How disable UI element on the loading stage

Tags: r, shiny

Let say I have a UI selector I would like to load it in the 'disabled' state without using "shinyjs" package. How setup options or any other elements to have this UI selector in the 'disabled' state from the beginning.

```
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_variable_x"))
)

# Server
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  # Variable 'X'
  output$uo_variable_x <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput(
      'si_variable_x', 
      label = NULL, 
      choices = state.name,
      selected = state.name[1:2],
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = list(
        create = TRUE
        # EXPECT some parameter here
      ))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perhaps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060782/disable-a-selectinput-in-r-shiny-when-not-required) might suffice.

Comment: thanks - but another one

Comment: Another solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831030/shiny-reactive-selectinput-in-r)